# Tinymce emoticons plugin doesn't adds image to the text

Tags: tinymce, emoticons

I'm using //cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.js

And recently I've added emoticons plugin.

I can see emojis in the toolbar, but with a click on emoji it doesn't adds to the text area.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: We cannot guess what are you doing! Please, provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any console errors when you click an emoticon? Does the HTML of your content change at all when you attempt to add an emoticon?

Comment: 1. No console errors.

2. No changes but the editor button "undo" becomes active after click on emoji.

The problem was in the next tinymce.init line:
`code` valid_elements: 'p,ul,li,ol,blockquote,br,-em/i,-strong/b/h1/h2/h3/h4/h5,-a[!name|!href|title|target],hr',
`code`
After add `img` everything works.
Thanks